# API parse String for Login system

Tags: api, next.js

Helle How can I Parse a String to api side?
I am Trying to Make a Login System. I have  the api side

```
import prisma from '../../lib/prisma'

export default async function handler(req, res) {


var user = 'admin'
var password = 'admin'
var email = 'admin@admin.com'

const db = await prisma.user.findMany({
                    where: {
                        username: user
                    }
                })
}
```

But I Can‘t find a way To get all the var's (user, email, password) form the Page I call the api.

Comment: Use a [dynamic API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/dynamic-api-routes) and pass the user name in the API URL.

Comment: @juliomalves sorry i described it wrong I need to pass more than one string like user, email and password. Can i also do it with dynamic API Route?

Comment: You can use a dynamic API route for that, but wouldn't it make more sense to send that through in the body of the request instead?

Comment: @juliomalves How can I send it through the req. Body?